# Python creating a list of list

Tags: python, list

I would like to know if there was a better way to create a list of list in which each list is a random permutation of an other list. This is what I coded to do it assuming numpy.random is import as rd :

```
def shuffle(L):
    i = rd.randint(0,len(L))
    j = rd.randint(0,len(L))
    L[i], L[j] = L[j], L[i]
    return 

list_base= [0,1,2,3]
list_of_list=[]
for k in range(4):
    M = list_base
    for i in range(5):
        shuffle(M)
    list_of_list.append(M[:])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `random.shuffle`?

```
import random
input_list = [0,1,2,3]
shuffled_lists = []
for x in range(4):
  lst = input_list[:]  # copy, since ...
  random.shuffle(lst)  # ... this modifies it in-place
  shuffled_lists.append(lst)

print(shuffled_lists)
```

outputs e.g.

```
[[1, 2, 3, 0], [2, 0, 3, 1], [0, 3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 0, 1]]
```

This will not guarantee that all permutations in `shuffled_lists` are unique though!

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools' permutation:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations as pm
>>> list_base= [0,1,2,3]
>>> random.choices(list(pm(list_base, len(list_base))), k = random.choice(range(1, len(list_base))) )
[(2, 1, 0, 3), (3, 2, 0, 1), (2, 0, 1, 3)]
```

The output then can be manually converted to list of list by one iteration.